# Why my docker cannot process php application?

Tags: docker-compose

I have the following docker-compose file :

```
version: '2'

services:
  phpfpm:
    tty: true # Enables debugging capabilities when attached to this container.
    image: 'bitnami/php-fpm:5.6'
    labels:
      kompose.service.type: nodeport
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
    volumes:
      - /usr/share/nginx/html:/app
    networks:
      - app-tier

  nginx:
    image: 'bitnami/nginx:latest'
    depends_on:
      - phpfpm
    networks:
      - app-tier
    links:
      - phpfpm
    ports:
      - '80:8080'
      - '443:8443'
    volumes:
      - ./my_vhost.conf:/bitnami/nginx/conf/vhosts/vhost.conf

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge
```

and here's the contents of my_vhost.conf file :

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:8080;

  root /app;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

  location /evodms {
    root /app/evodms;
    try_files $uri $uri /evodms/index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass phpfpm:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

  location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
  }
}
```

I have my applications within the /usr/share/nginx/html folder.

I have tried the following links :

- http://localhost => works, shows nginx homepage
- http://localhost/page.html => just an ordinary html file and works
- http://localhost/phpinfo.php => shows the php informations and works
- http://localhost/evodms, shows the following error messages from my
  docker :

> nginx_1   | nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "" on 0.0.0.0:8080,
>   ignored
>
> nginx_1   | 2017/12/08 15:13:29 [warn] 24#0: conflicting
>   server name "" on 0.0.0.0:8080, ignored
>
> nginx_1   | 2017/12/08 15:15:04 [error] 25#0: *1 FastCGI sent in
>   stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning: 
>   include(/usr/share/nginx/html/evodms/lib/LibCakePhp20unit/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /app/evodms/lib/LibCakePhp20unit/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 505
>
> nginx_1   | PHP message: PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening
>   '/usr/share/nginx/html/evodms/lib/LibCakePhp20unit/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php') in
>   /app/evodms/lib/LibCakePhp20unit/lib/Cake/Core/App.php on line 505
>
> nginx_1   | PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'CakePlugin' not
>   found in /app/evodms/app/Config/bootstrap.php on line 66" while
>   reading response header from upstream, client: 172.26.0.1, server: ,
>   request: "GET /evodms/ HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://172.26.0.2:9000", host: "localhost"
>
> nginx_1   | 172.26.0.1 - - [08/Dec/2017:15:15:04 +0000] "GET /evodms/
>   HTTP/1.1" 500 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100
>   Safari/537.36"

Any clue on what's going on for the issue on the last link?

Comment: Are you sure that file `/usr/share/nginx/html/evodms/lib/LibCakePhp20unit/lib/Cake/Core/CakePlugin.php` exists?

Comment: Also do you have local server (nginx, apache) and which port it used?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try with webdevops images which already include php-fpm and a webserver.

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    image: webdevops/php-nginx:7.2
    ports:
      - 9080:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    environment:
      - PHP_DEBUGGER=xdebug
      - PHP_DISPLAY_ERRORS=1
      - WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/app/public
```